# Ways to get the relative path of a folder

Tags: c#

I have one folder named "Images" in my project. I want to get the path of the Image folder so that I can browse that and get the files.

I'm using below piece of code for my above requirement and it is working fine.

```
string basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
basePath = basePath.Replace("bin", "#");
string[] str = basePath.Split('#');
basePath = str[0];
string path = string.Format(@"{0}{1}", basePath, "Images");
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(path);
  foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
         listBox.Items.Add(fileName);
```

Just want to know like is there any elegant way of doing this? What are the best ways of getting the folder path?

Comment: This is nothing to do with wpf

Comment: You can use [`Directory.GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) to retrieve the parent directory of a given directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what i usually use:

```
string appDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Note that this returns the directory of the assembly that contains the currently executing code (i assume this is your main executable).

To get the parent directory of the resulting path, you can also use

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(appDirectory);
```

I would advice against depending on the Visual Studio project structure in your code, though. Consider adding the images folder as content to your application, so that it resides in a subdirectory in the same directory as your executable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to reference a directory with a fixed relationship to another, then you can just use the same .. syntax you'd use at the command line?

You should also use the methods in the Path class (eg Path.Combine) rather than all that string manipulation.